# Angular - orderBy numeric value

Tags: json, angularjs

I have the next json -

```
{


  "json" : [

    { "200" : "5"},


    { "302" : "6"},


    { "400" : "1" }

  ]

}
```

and I would like to order it by the value in a descending order - meaning the order should be by the - the row with 6 than the one with 5 and at last the 1.

I tried to used the  ng-repeat like so:

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="(key, data) in json | orderBy: 'data':true">
             <tr>
                <td class="col-md-3">{{key}}</td>
                <td class="col-md-3">{{data}}</td>
            </tr>
  </tbody>
```

But this didn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: That's very strange data, can you change the structure of the JSON? So it at least has consistent keys from one item to the next? E.g.: http://pastie.org/10339296

Comment: the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#!) is very clear on this matter: when using `ng-repeat` to iterate over object properties, ordering is not guaranteed, and it is not possible to apply a sort without converting the data to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Your own order function.

Controller:

```
$scope.testFn = function(data){
    return data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
};
```

Template:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(key, data) in json | orderBy: testFn">
```

Comment: And `return -data[Object.keys(data)[0]];` for invert order;

Comment: I've tried this code and it doesn't seems to work. I even placed a -console.warn - to see if it get into the function, but it didn't. Any clue why?

Comment: @PESfcs I remake data like this: `$scope.json = [{ "200" : "5"},{ "302" : "6"},{ "400" : "1" }];` check data ng-repeat has gotten; (sorry for my english);

Comment: well in my case I needed - data[Object.keys(data)[1]] - but thanks fir your great help.